# Solving two second order differential equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, differential-equations

I'm beginner and MATLAB USER. I'm trying to solve a system of two differential second-order equations in Python, using odeint, but my graphs are different than expected.  I think something in my function is poorly defined.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

m1=100
m2=4.15
k1=120
k2=5
A1=1
A2=0
wn1=math.sqrt(k1/m1)
wn2=math.sqrt(k2/m2)
wf1=wn1
wf2=0
chi1=0.05
chi2=0.001
c1=2*chi1*wn1*m1
c2=2*chi2*wn2*m2

winicio=0.05
wpaso=0.01
wfin=2.5

T=2*math.pi/winicio
paso=0.05*T
tinicio=0
tfinal=T

yopos1=0
yovel1=0
yopos2=0
yovel2=0

def fy(y, t):
     return [y[2],
             y[3], 
             (-(c1+c2)*y[2] + c2*y[3] - (k1+k2)*y[0] + k2*y[1] + A1*math.sin(winicio*t))/m1,
             (-c2*(y[3]-y[2]) - k2*(y[1]-y[0]) + A2*math.sin(wf2*t))/m2]

tspan=np.linspace(tinicio, tfinal, 1000)
y0 = [yopos1, yopos2, yovel1, yovel2]
Ty = odeint(fy, y0, tspan)
ys1 = Ty[:,0]
ys2 = Ty[:,1]
vs1 = Ty[:,2]
vs2 = Ty[:,3]

plt.figure(1)          
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("position")
plt.title("GDL 1:Position-Time")
plt.plot(tspan,ys1,'r');
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("position")
plt.title("GDL 1:Position-Time")
plt.plot(tspan,ys2,'r');

plt.figure(2)          
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Velocity")
plt.title("GDL 1:Velocity-Time")
plt.plot(tspan,vs1,'r',);
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Velocity")
plt.title("GDL 2:Velocity-Time")
plt.plot(tspan,vs2,'r');
```

But I used the same method and the same function in Matlab and my graphics work very well:

```matlab
fy=@(t,y) [y(3);
          y(4);
          (-(c1+c2)*y(3)+c2*y(4)-(k1+k2)*y(1)+k2*y(2)+A1*sin(winicio*t))/m1;
          (-c2*(y(4)-y(3))-k2*(y(2)-y(1))+A2*sin(wf2*t))/m2];

tspan=tinicio:paso:tfin; % Intervalo de tiempo
yopos=[yopos1;yopos2;yovel1;yovel2]; % Condiciones iniciales
[t,y]=ode45(fy,tspan,yopos); % Resolución ec. dif
n=length(t);

figure(1) % Gráficas 1.Posición-t y Velocidad-t

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,y(:,1),'b'); % GDL 1: posición-tiempo
xlim([0 t(n)]);
hold on; grid on; grid minor
xlabel('Tiempo')
ylabel('Posición')
title('Gdl 1: Posición-Tiempo')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,y(:,2),'r'); % GDL 2: posición-tiempo
xlim([0 t(n)]);
hold on; grid on,grid minor
xlabel('Tiempo')
ylabel('Posición')
title('Gdl 2: Posición-Tiempo')
```

Please can someone help me and say what it is wrong?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXnHv.png]

Comment: Please repeat the experiment using python 3 or, if impossible, add at the top `from __future__ import division` so that all divisions are floating point divisions.

Comment: Are you completely sure that the constants are the same in both versions? At least the computation of `tfin` has to be different from the one for `tfinal=T`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The tfinal and tfin constants are the same for both cases (T). I think the problem is in the function of the two second order equations, because I already performed the same procedure for a second order equation with similar conditions, and the results in Python and Matlab were the same. The top from __future__ import division did not work, but thanks for your time.

Comment: I can not reproduce your graph. `T` has a value about 130, if I take the constants from the python variant, the matlab code produces a graph that is much less oscillating, containing exactly one oscillation. Are you sure that you started from a clean workspace?

Comment: Are you merely sure or have you actually checked that the two parameter sets are the same?

Comment: Okay, what happens is that the code fragment I posted above is only part of the complete code. I think I post the most important part and where the error is, and if you run it, it shows the graphs of that function. If you want and have the time, I can send you the complete code in python and matlab. What I did is take that fragment and just reprogram the function to see that the graphs are consistent with the function.

Comment: if you compare the T and the tfinal of the complete code with only the fragment of the post, there will be a difference, because the complete code has a while function of iteration of the conditions of Tinicio and Tfinal. But I already found the solution, so simple that you only have to change the winicio of the function to the value 1, the harmonic force. What happens is that in the complete code apart from the time iteration, there is the iteration of the winicio condition that is the system frequency.

Comment: Which indicates that the problem with my complete code is not in the function, but in another place.
Anyway, thanks for the review, and for your time. If you are interested I can send you for your knowledge, only that it is in Spanish, because I am a Latin American student.
Thanks a lot Dr. for your time and your answers, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your English is good enough, no problems there. Yes, it is a problem to discuss more complex code and problems stemming from parts "higher up in the hierarchy". To reduce this to a minimal working example suitable for this platform can be difficult to impossible. // Do you use events in Matlab or consider it? Then you might want to switch to the `solve_ivp` interface to also use events in the python implementation.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem (if it still is one) in the broader context you spoke about on some typical mock-up problem like the Lotka-Volterra equations or Vander-Pol oscillator? The point being less constants and less overhead for the inner ODE formulation, so that the control of the parameters (as this is what the outer loop does?) does still fit in the frame of this platform. If you do, it might make sense to open a new question and terminate this one is some way.